# How to draw Range Chart MpAndroidChart with negative and positive value?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to draw Chart in my App. I have a problem when my Chart display data with value from negavite to positive.I reseached example of this lib by using BarChart but have not solution.
E.g. Column 1 will draw from -10 to 30. (has minValue and maxValue)
I don't know how to do that, BarChart is always draw from zero line.
I am setting like below:

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'

YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100);
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(-100);
float[] data = new float[]{-10f, 30f};
values.add(new BarEntry(1, data));
```

But have not effect. Please help me.
I want to draw chart like this image bellow:
[image]

Comment: have you set `setStartAtZero(false)`?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#examples If so, you should show your research.

Comment: @SarantisTofas, your method was replace by setAxisMinimum method.

Comment: @jdv, thanks, I have research examples before I coding. But I don't know. Do you have other suggestion for me?

Comment: You should share, in the question, that you have already researched the _official_ examples and not found an answer.

Comment: @Mr.TuanLe The `setAxisMinimum` method accepts a float number, you are giving it an integer. Try with `setAxisMinimum(-100f)`

Comment: @SarantisTofas, auto casting from integer to float, this is not problem.

Comment: I'm use CandleStickChart and this problem is done.

Comment: @Tuan Could you share how you plot the values? My graph is inaccurately placed on Y axis. I heard this is the default behaviour with CandleStickChart as data is being handled as it was stock data. How did you overcome this to use for temperature? Thanks

Comment: You can see a tutorial about CandleStickCart in this link 
https://medium.com/@neerajmoudgil/candlestick-chart-using-philjay-mpandroidchart-library-how-to-bf657ddf3a28
Refer to file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a3BgyOa-BbXlZ8cUcnDM-aVUpV57cT_X/view?usp=sharing
Hope you understand :)